# Unable to install Sass v4.10 after run the command "ng add @angular/pwa"

Tags: node.js, sass

I built a new project by using the command

```
"ng new Client --style=scss --routing"
```

After that, I ran the command

```
"ng add @angular/pwa"
```

Then I try to run

```
"npm start"
```

it pops up the below messages:

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.sassLoader (C:\xampp\htdocs\client\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:72) i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

I tried to use the command

```
"npm install --unsafe-perm=true"
```

then use

```
"npm install node-sass"
```

still came out error message:

```
2319 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
2320 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
2321 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS: darwin
2321 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch: any
2321 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS: win32
2321 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
2322 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.9.3 (node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\node-sass):
2323 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall: node scripts/build.js
2323 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
2324 verbose optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
2324 verbose optional Failed at the node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall script.
2324 verbose optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2325 verbose stack Error: node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall: node scripts/build.js
2325 verbose stack Exit status 1
2325 verbose stack at EventEmitter. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
2325 verbose stack at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
2325 verbose stack at ChildProcess. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
2325 verbose stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
2325 verbose stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
2325 verbose stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
2326 verbose pkgid node-sass@4.10.0
2327 verbose cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\client
2328 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
2329 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "node-sass"
2330 verbose node v10.13.0
2331 verbose npm v6.4.1
2332 error code ELIFECYCLE
2333 error errno 1
2334 error node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall: node scripts/build.js
2334 error Exit status 1
2335 error Failed at the node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall script.
2335 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2336 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Is there anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is being solved by

npm install --global --production windows-build-tools,

It will guide the node to install python and all the necessary tools to load sass

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

> npm rebuild node-sass

Comment: My solution was "npm install --global --production windows-build-tools"

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below command

**Try 1**

```
 npm install node-sass
```

**Try 2**: remove node_modules folder and run npm install

```
rm -rf node_modules
run npm install
```

**Try 3**

```
npm install --save node-sass
```